# What is the difference between clientRequest and response object in an https post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I am trying to make an https post request on an external server and am confused with how clientRequest and the response parameter differ :

```
const options =
{
   method : "POST",
   auth : "api-key-here"
};

const x = https.request(url, options, function(request,response)
{
   // some code
});

// x is the clientRequest
x.write(someData);

x.end();
```

I know that response is what the server sends back on making a request. But then, what is clientRequest? Does the https.request function send it in addition to a response? If yes, then what's the difference between them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. [`ClientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) has an `end` method ,but no `send` method.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yeah, my mistake. Please check now, I modified the question.

Comment: The request is what has been sent to the server and the response is what came back from the server after sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

the variable "x" which is your "clientRequest" is the request you are creating, while the "request" parameter is used to store and display the result of that request.
You can find more information in:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http

Comment: Isn't the result of the request stored in the response parameter?

Comment: yes, that's why you can access: request.params or request.body and so on.